# Result of convolving two $3\times3$ kernels

Tags: convolution, image-processing

I am new to image processing and I just read that the associative property of the convolution operation allows us to convolve multiple kernels into a single one before applying that single kernel onto the image. I am confused as to the dimension of the output kernel. If we are given an image input $f$ and 2 kernels, $g$ and $h$, the associativity law stats that we can convolve $f$ with $(g*h)$. If $g$ and $h$ are two $3\times 3$ kernels, then the output of $(g*h)$ will be  $1\times 1$  kernel ? This is based on my knowledge on how convolution works in image processing.

Comment: The convolution of two $3\times3$ kernels is a $5\times5$ kernel. You sweep the center of one over the other.

Comment: @YvesDaoust could you elaborate what that means in the context of image processing ? In terms of 2D pixel arrays how would that work

Comment: This *is* in the context of 2D pixel arrays.

Comment: @calveeen this video is quite helpful in explaining the convolution! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_zFhWdM4ic

Comment: @Zim. I have watched the video but it shows that the result of the convolution yields a image that is smaller than the original. That is my understanding of how convolution works in images and the source of my confusion. They add additional Borders to preserve The size of the original image

Comment: @calveeen The video was mostly to supplement the "sweeping" notion discussed by Yves.

Let us visualize the process of sweeping the kernel over the image. *The full convolution is mathematically well-defined anywhere the kernel can overlap with the image.* This includes cases when some values do not overlap, e.g. when the bottom right corner of the kernel is on top of the top left corner of the image.

In the video, they only keep the most "central" part of the convolution, which is the same size as the input.

Comment: @calveeen In the context of your example: the $(1,1)$ entry of $g*h$ would be only $g(3,3)\cdot h(1,1)$. Likewise, the $(5,5)$ entry of $g*h$ would be $g(1,1)\cdot h(3,3)$, etc. These edge cases are the points which make the result of the convolution a larger image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ and $h$ are two $3\times 3$ kernels, then $(g*h)$ will be a $5\times 5$ kernel. In general, when convolving two signals of length $m$ and $n$, then the result will have length $m+n-1$.

So the law states that convolving $f$ with two $3\times 3$ kernels $g$ and $h$ yields the same result as convolving $f$ with the $5\times 5$ kernel $g*h$.

EDIT: There appears to be some confusion about how the result of a convolution can be larger. The image below shows how some of the entries in $g*h$ are constructed, using only a few entries of $g$ and $h$. [image]

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. For image processing however, why is it the case that the convolution of image with a kernel results in a image that is smaller ?

Comment: @calveeen that is typically not the case in my experience in image processing. The convolution always yields a resulting signal which is larger than the initial signals. However, if you are observing a signal that was smaller than the input, then the image (after convolution) was probably downsampled or truncated. It is quite common in compression schemes to first convolve an image, then downsample.

Comment: Thank you for the visualisation, it is much clearer now how the kernel size becomes bigger. However, how are the pixel values for the convolution computed ? From what I understand the middle pixel value is computed by taking a weighted average of its surroundings. In this case, there are no "middle pixels" except when the 2 kernels overlap fully.

Comment: Yup, the weighted average notion is correct! We multiply each of the overlapping entries of $h$ and $g$ (denoted with the blue X in the image), then sum them all up. If entries do not overlap, they are not included in the sum. This is also called "zero edge padding," since all of the entries that don't overlap are ignored. This is the type of convolution your law is describing. However, beware that there are other operators, also called ["convolution"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Edge_Handling),
which handle edges differently.

Comment: It's also worth noting that sometimes it's not *technically* an average (in the sense that the weights might not always be positive, add to $1$, etc). Each entry is certainly a weighted sum though.

Comment: thank you for your help so far ! I am still kind of confused because when applying filters to images, only the original size of the image is preserved, which is quite different from what you have drawn in the illustration. How does the law apply when we have a kernel size $mxm$ convolved with an image of size $hxn$ ? What would be the size of the actual output

Comment: @calveeen The "full" convolution is the one which yields a larger image, and that is the type of convolution for which the law (in the question) holds. The full convolution size in your example is $m+h-1\times m+n-1$.

It can be confusing because, in image processing, it is common to only keep the central-most portion of the convolution (so it remains the same size as the original image) and discard the rest. For instance, in Octave, two very similar operations which yield differently-sized results, are provided by `conv2(A,B,'same')` and `conv2(A,B,'full')`.

Comment: i see. Thank you for the clarification !